# Wireshark dissector development - Reassembly tcp frames

Tags: tcp, wireshark

Just before starting, sorry for my english... i'm french.

I'm developing (in C language) a wireshark dissector to dissect a specific protocol to the company (it's owner of it) where I work but I have a problems when messages are several TCP frames ... I can not reassemble the messages when a message is broken into two different frames TCP, I can not reform it in one message...

I read the readme.dissector and try using two methods:

- First method:

  > ```
  > tcp_dissect_pdus(tvb, pinfo, tree, dns_desegment, 2,
  >             get_dns_pdu_len, dissect_dns_tcp_pdu, data);
  >         return tvb_captured_length(tvb);
  > ```
- Second method :

  > ```
  > guint offset = 0;
  >     while(offset < tvb_reported_length(tvb)) {
  >         gint available = tvb_reported_length_remaining(tvb, offset);
  >         gint len = tvb_strnlen(tvb, offset, available);
  >
  >         if( -1 == len ) {
  >             /* we ran out of data: ask for more */
  >             pinfo->desegment_offset = offset;
  >             pinfo->desegment_len = DESEGMENT_ONE_MORE_SEGMENT;
  >             return (offset + available);
  >         }
  >
  >         col_set_str(pinfo->cinfo, COL_INFO, "C String");
  >
  >         len += 1; /* Add one for the '\0' */
  >
  >         if (tree) {
  >             proto_tree_add_item(tree, hf_cstring, tvb, offset, len,
  >                 ENC_ASCII|ENC_NA);
  >         }
  >         offset += (guint)len;
  >     }
  >
  >     /* if we get here, then the end of the tvb coincided with the end of a
  >        string. Happy days. */
  >     return tvb_captured_length(tvb);
  > ```

But impossible to reassemble the message, I do not understand why ... can you help me please?
I hope you understand my problem ...: /

Comment: You might want to try asking this in the wireshark developers mailing list: 
https://www.wireshark.org/mailman/listinfo/wireshark-dev